# why laravel Redirecting to the login page after fail request validation api?

Tags: php, laravel

I am using default Request for a public method in controller, when I use validation required and don't pass the required params in api payload with postman , it just redirect me to login page and does not show any validate rule message.

my method :

```
class OrderController extends Controller
{
    public function createOrder(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'name' => 'required',
            'phone' => 'required',
            'address' => 'required',
            'wallet_id' => 'required'
        ]);
        return 'something';
    }
}
```

with this route:

```
Route::post('/createOrder', 'OrderController@createOrder')->middleware('auth:api');
```

in postman (or application) when I don't send one of required parameters, it redirect me to login page.

thanks in advance

Comment: When validation fails, it usually redirects back to the submitting page. If that route is also a POST route, it may redirect somewhere else. Open up your browser's developer console and watch the Network tab when you submit to see how many redirects there are.

Comment: You are using middleware `auth:api` , I think you're not authenticated that's why it sends back you on login, please make sure you're passing `Authorization` in header

Answer (score -1):

In Postman, in your request, in Headers tab set `Accept` key and `application/json` as value. In this way your *Authenticate* middleware should avoid redirection in case you are not authenticated.

The default Authenticate middleware:

```
class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     */
    protected function redirectTo(Request $request): ?string
    {
        return $request->expectsJson() ? null : route('login');
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I found it,
just need to create a custom request and make method `failedValidation` in the custom request and return `HttpResponseException` like below:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException;

class CreateShoppingRequest extends FormRequest
{
/**
 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required',
        'phone' => 'required',
        'address' => 'required',
        'wallet_id' => 'required'
    ];
}

public function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
{
    throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json([
        'data' => null,
        'status' => 'validation_error',
        'message' => 'error on insert required data',
        'validation' => $validator->errors()
    ], 400));
}
}
```

and in my controller implement the custom request:

```
use App\Http\Requests\CreateShoppingRequest;
class OrderController extends Controller
{
    public function createOrder(CreateShoppingRequest $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'name' => 'required',
            'phone' => 'required',
            'address' => 'required',
            'wallet_id' => 'required'
        ]);
        return 'something';
    }
}
```